# Ruby on Rails: Controller Not Evaluating Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

The `next comment` button should be directed to `http://localhost:3000/articles/14/comments/70`.

What it currently executes is: `http://localhost:3000/articles/14/comments/56/next_comment`

How does one fix this?

```
#button
= link_to "next comment", next_comment_article_comment_path(@article, @comment)

#controller
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def next_comment 
    @comment ||= @scope.next(@comment)
  end

  def scope
    @scope ||= @article.comments
  end
end
```

UPDATE

```
#routes.rb
resources :articles do
 resources :comments do
  member do
    get 'next_comment'
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you update your question with `routes.rb` code?

Comment: any clue whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `rake routes` and check if there is a route to `next_comment_article_comment_path(@article, @comment)`

And try whith: `article_comment_next_comment_path(@article, @comment)`

Comment: The route itself is working and of course appearing under `rake routes`, the problem is that the method is not executing.

Comment: mmm... I'm not understanding where you are calling scope method, you are accessing to `@scope` who must be nill in that moment..
Why you aren't doing this?

`def next_comment; @comment ||= scope.next(params[:comment]); end`

`def scope; @scope ||= params[:article].comments; end`

Comment: Makes sense, but I don't think that's why the method is not executing.